# How to update a mongoose's array item

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document in a mongodb collection like this :

```
{
   id: String,
   username: String,
   password: String,
   email: String,
   user_messeges: [{
                     mail:String,
                     messeges:[ {String} ]
                  }]
}
```

And i want to update messeges array in user_messeges array.

i used this method but i got error: "The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query. Unexpected update"

```
User.update({'user_messeges.email':my_email},{$push : {'user_messeges.$.messages':msg}},{upsert:true},function(err)...
```

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Just test the following query against your schema and it works.

```
   db.user.update({'user_messeges.mail':'some_email'},
{$push:{'user_messeges.$.messeges':'new msg'}},
{upsert:true})
```